# How to reshape multiple dimensions with constraints

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to achieve this behavior using reshape. I'm new to matlab so I've been struggling a bit.

I have a

3 x 2 x 5 matrix called A

And I would like to merge dimensions 1 through 5, excluding 4. When combining them I want to retain the columns within each row in order.

I know I can do something like

A = reshape(A, [12, 2, 1]) but my concerns are this may not retain the order of the columns within each row and it doesn't allow me to exclude a dimension.

Example:

```
(:,:,1) =

0.3168    3.1825
1.5841    1.5766
-0.7892    3.0073


(:,:,2) =

-0.2131    3.9708
2.9435    0.4964
-0.2131    2.5985

(:,:,3) =

0.5012    -3.5328
0.4551    2.1314
-1.5956    3.4161

(:,:,4) =

-0.12    -3.28
-0.51    -2.14
-1.56    -3.61


(:,:,5) =

6.5012    3.538
0.4551    0.314
-0.5956    0.411
```

Output, let's say of combining all dimension except the 4th one

```
0.3168    3.1825
1.5841    1.5766
-0.7892    3.0073
-0.2131    3.9708
2.9435    0.4964
-0.2131    2.5985
0.5012    -3.5328
0.4551    2.1314
-1.5956    3.4161
6.5012    3.538
0.4551    0.314
-0.5956    0.411
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want through clever use of `reshape`, as you mentioned, as well as indexing. In addition, you will need to use `permute` (which switches dimensions around), because you want to keep each 'slice' intact.

First off, it is good to know that you can exclude your 4th slice using indexing. Consider the following example:

```
A = randi(100,3,2,5)
idxdim3 = [1,2,3,5];     % Create an array of integers corresponding to the slices you want
B = A(:,:,idxdim3)       % Extract all the slices you want, discarding the 4th
```

This will leave you with an array of size [3 x 2 x 4] in this case. Next, you can try to use `reshape`, but you will encounter a problem. `reshape` works its way up the dimensions, columns being the first dimension, rows being the second, and 'slices' being the third. As you said, you want to keep the columns within each row in order, but `reshape` will alter those before it will commence work in the third dimension. So we need to make the second and third dimension switch place first using `permute`:

```
% Leave 1 as the first dimension, but switches dimensions 2 and 3 around:
C = permute(B,[1 3 2]);
```

Now we can `reshape` to the appropriate size:

```
D = reshape(C,[12 2 1]);
```

Which should give you the result you are looking for. Of course, we can combine most of these statements into a single line, like so:

```
A = randi(100,3,2,5);  % Put your data here instead
idxdim3 = [1,2,3,5];
B = reshape( permute( A(:,:,idxdim3), [1 3 2]), 12, 2);
```

Note: if you will work with different-size `A`'s in the future, you can let `reshape` calculate one of the dimensions if you specify the others. The following will also work:

```
B = reshape( permute( A(:,:,idxdim3), [1 3 2]), [], 2);
```

`reshape` will calculate the `12` for you.

**Example output:**

```
A(:,:,1) =
44    80
39    19
77    49
A(:,:,2) =
45    76
65    28
71    68
A(:,:,3) =
66    50
17    96
12    35
A(:,:,4) =
59    26
23    51
76    70
A(:,:,5) =
90    14
96    15
55    26

B =
44    80
39    19
77    49
45    76
65    28
71    68
66    50
17    96
12    35
90    14
96    15
55    26
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of `permute` and `reshape`:

```
% delete A[:,:,4]
B = A(:,:,[1:3,5])
% permute dimension 2 and 3, because you want to concatenate your array according to the 3nd dimension before the 2nd dimension.
C = permute(B,[1 3 2])
% Use reshape with the first parameter beeing '[]' so matlab will automatically compute the number of line needed, the number of column is fixed: it's 2 or size(B,2)
C = reshape(C,[],size(B,2))
```

Comment: Not to be rude or anyting, but why would you post an answer with **exactly** the same information and solution as mine, even the same variable names? You have not provided anything I have not, and your answer was added an hour after mine. It really just looks like you copied the code lines from my answer and posted them in your own.

Comment: @FlorisSA Hi, I posted this answer 6 minutes after yours, I haven't noticed that an answer had already been posted before I posted mine. I haven't deleted my answer for two reasons: 1) In my opinion your answer is too long, so it's hard to get the main informations in less than 15 secondes. 2) You fixed the dimension size in your answer, making the snippet non generalizable.